# Google Play Services and NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, wear-os

I had an app working alright until today. To do some integration with a wearable module (I use Android Studio), I had to update Google Play Services from 6.1.0 to 7.3.0 (the latest). I also use an external library, which I know it works fine and there is no problem with it.

The thing is when I update my gradle file with the new Google Play Services version, I get the NoClassDefFoundError at runtime (complaining on my external library). I've tried everything, but nothing works (made sure the .jar is ok, that is actually exported, cleaned 1000 times, rebuild, delete build folder, etc). If I set the Google Play Services to 6.1.11 back, the app run as it used to be.

This is driving me crazy...

My build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
compile files('libs/mylibrary.jar')
```

}

The error log:

```
05-06 15:23:56.544  31574-31574/com.rippll.okchat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rippll.okchat, PID: 31574
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/rippll/geowave/Geowave;
        at com.rippll.okchat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:92)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.rippll.geowave.Geowave" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rippll.okchat-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at com.rippll.okchat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:92)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.rippll.geowave.Geowave
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
        ... 16 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rippll.geowave.Geowave
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Wear doesn't support Google Play Services v7.x yet.

So, you need to use Google Play Services v6.x in your Wearable project, for example in your `build.gradle` file of wear project:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

But in your mobile (handheld) project you can use latest v7.x library version, if you're really need it, like:

```
dependencies {
    wearApp project(':yourWearProjectName')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0+'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you sure about that? According to the documentation I think it supports Google Play Services 7.3. In fact, inside of that version we can find com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.3.0 (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

If I want to send messages from the wearable app to the phone app...do I need to have the same version of Google Play services in both modules?

Comment: Besides, using google play services 6.5.87 just in the app gradle, I get the same runtime error...NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Maven repository contains 7.3.0 version of every Play services module.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit of ~65000 methods for your .apk. Google Play services grow in size with each release and when you include them in your project you may very well jump over that method count limit. The solution is to use only the modules you need.

Please read carefully https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I tried this too, still got the runtime error.

Comment: Do you get the error after using proguard? Have you tried running `gradlew lint` and analysing results/fixing errors?